# How to set timeout for BigQuery API request in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Sometimes when we poll for a BigQuery job, our request ends up with `SocketTimeoutException`. You can see the code raising the exception below.

```
this.bigquery.jobs().get(projectNumber, jobId).execute();
```

And here is the error message we get.

```
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
Timeout while fetching URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/######/jobs/######
...
```

My question is if there is a way to extend the timeout. And does anyone know what the default timeout is?

Comment: is this done directly in code or as a task queue?  be aware that you still need, even if you play with your timeouts, to limit yourself to the 1 minute limit for hitting a url, or the 10 minutes limit for task queues

Comment: If I exceeded the frontend instance deadline, I would get `DeadlineExceededException`. This is definitely related to BigQuery API call.

Comment: oh I'm aware of the difference between the socket and deadline timeout.  I just meant be careful about increasing your deadline so as to NOT hit the other error ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap the credential object in a HTTP initializer that disables (or extends) timeouts. That is, where you currently have this:

```
Credential credential = ...
Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
```

you could do

```
final Credential credential = ...
HttpRequestInitializer initializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
  public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
    credential.initialize(request);
    request.connectTimeout = request.readTimeout = 0;
  }
}
Bigquery bigquery = new Bigquery(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, initializer);
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/) for BigQuery object javadoc, [this](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart) for BigQuery object creation example,   and [this](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.3-beta/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer.html?is-external=true) for HttpRequestInitializer overloading.

Comment: And how can I use such a connection along with BigQuery API client? Actually I retry the request if it fails, however, I would like to extend the timeout anyway.

Comment: Hmm... I had thought that this method was static. I've updated my answer to hopefully work. If it doesn't, let me know and I'll ping the internal google apis folks.

Comment: Hey @JordanTigani, is this still the preferred way to mitigate the timeouts? Been hitting them a lot lately (from an App Engine instance in the same project as BQ)

Answer (score 1):

If it is the  **request**  only that you want to set a timeout to then in request body:

`query_config = {
            'timeoutMs': 1000,`

set timeoutsMs to whatever you like withing reason ;)

Hope that helps the documentation is  [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query)

**Edit**

To get the results of the query even if it hasn't obeyed the timeout Call `jobs.getQueryResults` taken from the site you must specify a start row, and this also takes a timeout that behaves the same as the jobs.query timeout to allow waiting if the job is not yet complete.

Comment: This is related to query job only. I need to set a timeout for any BigQuery API request.

Comment: It only solves query requests. I am concerned with timeout related to API calls to retrieve any BigQuery job (query, load, extract, link).

Answer (score 0):

I had to increase HTTP timeout in BigQuery client. But I used [newer version of BigQuery client](https://github.com/googlearchive/bigquery-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java) (`com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery` package) where it should be done in a different way (not like in
[old BigQuery client](https://github.com/googlearchive/bigquery-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/samples/BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.java) `com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery` package)

```
BigQuery createBigQueryConnection(String projectId) {
            return BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .setTransportOptions(HttpTransportOptions.newBuilder()
                            .setConnectTimeout(100)
                            .setReadTimeout(100)
                            .build())
                    .build()
                    .getService();
}
```